# How to only suppress SQL*Plus banner messages when running sql script from python

Tags: python, sqlplus

I have been executing Oracle SQL scripts from Python for a long time but never found a way to only suppress the banner and the connect and disconnect messages of SQL*Plus.

SQL*Plus itself is invoked with some code like this:

```py
session = subprocess.Popen(
    args=['sqlplus', '-S', '-L', username+'/'+password+'@'+server), "@{}".format(script)],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=sys.stdout,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )

try:
    session.communicate(timeout=timeout)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    session.kill()
    session.communicate()
    
code = session.returncode
```

I'm aware that SQL*Plus has the `-S` silent option and this would suppress the banner, but when using the silent option SQL*Plus also suppresses (even in the spool file) the echoing of commands.

Did someone find a way to just suppress the SQL*Plus banner and the connect and disconnect messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in SQL*Plus: Bug 17328625